# Obj.apply(Obj): is it safe and performant?

Tags: javascript, oop

I came up with a simple design pattern that was inspired by several other design patterns. Its main purpose is to have private methods (instead of all global), methods visually nested and grouped within an object, and having "self" as an available variable to access the scope, which is really useful when using calling functions with a callback parameter.

It *seems* to work fine, but is it safe (performance - and scope-wise) to do `Obj.apply(Obj);`?

The code:

```
function Obj() {

    var self = this;

    var privateFunc = function() {
        console.log('private');
        self.otherPublic();
    };

    self.publicFunc = function() {
        console.log('pub1ic');
        privateFunc();
    };

    self.otherPublic = function() {
        console.log('pub2');
    };

} Obj.apply(Obj);
```

I call it like this:

```
Obj.publicFunc();
```

Comment: --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally pointless brother. What you're doing by `Obj.apply(Obj);` is taking the function Obj, and adding to it those methods, in an unintuitive manner.

This:

```
var Obj = (function(){

  var priv = function(){ console.log('2'); },
      privVar = 6;

  return {
      pub1: function(){ console.log('1'); },
      pub2: function(){ priv(); }
  };

})();
```

Does the same thing, although better. I say better because (1) it's intuitive, and (2) `Obj` is now a simple javascript object (`typeof Obj === 'object'`) whereas your `Obj` is a function with properties augmented (`typeof Obj === 'function'`).

If you want a reference to `self` it's not hard (although it seems unnecessary), just create the object which will be returned at the top of the function, and augment the public methods, either at the end, or as you make them...

It's safe, but pointless.

Also, note that these methods won't scale well, because for each instance of `Obj` we create each function is recreated, which is memory-wise wasteful. This pattern above is fine because we created it with an anonymous function, so by definition there can only be one instance, although for types you need to instantiate multiple times the prototype should be used.

Don't be scared of it, it's there to be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

```
var Obj = (function(){

  var priv = function(){ pub2(); },
      privVar = 6,
      pub1 = function(){ priv(); },
      pub2 = function(){ console.log('1'); };

  return {
      pub1: pub1,
      pub2: pub2
  };

})();

Obj.pub1();
```

Notice that I call a public function, which calls a private function, which calls a public function - no special binding, no object reference.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
var Obj = (function(){

  var public = {},
      priv = function(){ public.pub2(); },
      privVar = 6;

  public.pub1 = function(){ priv(); },
  public.pub2 = function(){ console.log('1'); };

  return public;

})();

Obj.pub1();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I know this pattern, but the problem I have with it is this: When I call a public method, which calls a private method, the private methods cannot call any public methods (without specifying the object), unless I keep a separate object that returns all public functions like `return {pub1: pub1, pub2: pub2};`.  Also, I'd have to bind or apply scope every time I do a callback function.

Comment: @Blaise, then you haven't setup your scope nicely, I'll edit my answer with an example...

Comment: @Blaise: you edited your comment, so now I see that you don't want to return the `{pub1:pub1,...}` object. Why not?

Comment: In the ideal situation, I want to specify public/private when I define the function, otherwise I have to update that list separately. That's how I ended up with `Obj.apply(Obj);`. It's a matter of preference maybe, if there's no way around it I might adjust my preference...  :)

Comment: @Blaise, that's it? I'll update my answer again and show you how that can be done with the same pattern...